# Can someone please tell me why I am getting HTTP Status 406 from Spring

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Can someone please tell me why I am getting HTTP Status 406 from Spring?  I am trying to make spring return some json code and I am getting back a 406 status..

Here is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public  User getDisplayDefault(ModelMap model) {
      return new User("user name", "userid");
}
```

now here is my javaconfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xxxx.mvc.web"})
public class WebMVCConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebMVCConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver resolver()
    {
        UrlBasedViewResolver url = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        url.setPrefix("/views/");
        url.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        url.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return url;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        logger.debug("setting up resource handlers");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/").addResourceLocations("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer)
    {
        logger.debug("configureDefaultServletHandling");
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver simpleMappingExceptionResolver()
    {
        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver b = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

        Properties mappings = new Properties();
        mappings.put("org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound", "p404");
        mappings.put("org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException", "dataAccessFailure");
        mappings.put("org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException", "dataAccessFailure");
        b.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
        return b;
    }
}
```

so I really don't understand why my json is not coming back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Jackson/Jackson2 libs on your classpath? If not Spring will create no message converters. From the docs:

- MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter (or MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter) converts to/from JSON — added if Jackson 2 (or Jackson) is present on the classpath.

Comment: the issue was the maven did not find the version I was looking for